# Hiding SoftKeyboard when button inside dialog is clicked

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have custom dialog where inside its xml has a Submit button that whenever clicked, it should dismiss the softKeyboard.
I have the following code:

MainActivity.kt (Inherits from BaseActivity)

```
val updateDialog = Dialog(this, R.style.CustomDialog)
                updateDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_update)

val tvSubmitToFirestore = updateDialog.findViewById<HelveticaBoldTextView>(R.id.tv_update_item)

tvSubmitToFirestore.setOnClickListener {

                    hideKeyboard(currentFocus ?: View(this))
                }
```

BaseActivity:

```
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    //hide keyboard when instance of an event
    fun Context.hideKeyboard(view: View) {
        val inputMethodManager = getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }
}
```

But the keyboard remains on its position after clicking the said button.

Update:

```
//update item
            val tvUpdate = showItemDialog.findViewById<HelveticaNormalTextView>(R.id.tv_update)
            tvUpdate.setOnClickListener {
                //close search dialog
                showItemDialog.dismiss()

                val updateDialog = Dialog(this, R.style.CustomDialog)
                updateDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_update)
                updateDialog.setCancelable(false)

                //spinner settings
                val spinner = updateDialog.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.sp_update)
                populateSpinner(spinner, dialogProductCategory.text.toString())

                //set default values of update dialog fields == the current product's properties(name, category, price)
                val etProductName = updateDialog.findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.et_update_product_name)
                val etProductPrice = updateDialog.findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.et_update_product_price)

                etProductName.setText(dialogProdName.text.toString())
                etProductPrice.setText(dialogProductPrice.text.toString())

                //update item
                val tvSubmitToFirestore = updateDialog.findViewById<HelveticaBoldTextView>(R.id.tv_update_item)

                //TODO allow user to update an item with the same name provided that it should only exist once
                // and must be unique

                tvSubmitToFirestore.setOnClickListener {

//                    hideKeyboard(currentFocus ?: tvSubmitToFirestore)
                    hideKeyboard1(it, this@MainActivity)

                    val newProductName = etProductName.text.toString().trim()
                    val newProductCategory = spinner.selectedItem.toString().uppercase()
                    val newProductPrice = etProductPrice.text.toString().toDouble()

                    GlobalScope.launch {
                        validateProduct(newProductName, newProductCategory, newProductPrice)
                    }

                    //TODO : allow user to reuse the product name when updating

                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the new `WindowInsetsController` library to hide and show keyboard. Use this function:

```kotlin
fun hideKeyboard(view: View, activity: Activity) {
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat(activity.window, view).hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
}
```

In your case, you call use it like this:

```kotlin
tvSubmitToFirestore.setOnClickListener { view ->
    hideKeyboard(view, this) // 'this' refers to MainActivity
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this using your code:
```
 hideKeyboard1(tvSubmitToFirestore, this@MainActivity)
```

Did I execute it properly? SoftKeyboard is still show up even clicking the button.

Comment: I tried your updated answer  but still, it doesn't work.

Comment: I use this function in my projects and it always works. Can you add some more of you code in the question? Particularly the dialog and edit text statements..

Comment: Please do check my updated post sir. I guess something is making things not to work properly.

Comment: Try this one `activity.window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN)`

Comment: Is it supposed to look like this?

fun hideKeyboard1(activity: Activity) {
        activity.window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN)
    }

Comment: Yeah, the view parameter would be then redundant here. But did it work?

Comment: Too bad. It still did not fix it. My app do this steps. I have a custom dialog. Then there a button there that says "Update". When I click this button, this dismisses the previous dialog and opens an another dialog(this will make sure that I only have one dialog running) Then I would click the button Update once again and it should dismiss the keyboard.

Comment: Try this `updateDialog.window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN)`. Write this in the click listener itself.

Comment: Still not working. Everything solution you offer makes sense. I guess I'll try to check the whole code and check if there is something that I missed out.